# pgagent not working and not showing the statics in pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, centos7, pgagent

I have installed the pgAgent try to run the jobs. it is not working no statics are showing the pgadmin.

I checked the logs

```
ERROR: Stopping pgAgent: Couldn't establish the primary connection with the database server.
```

please help.

Thank you, Raja

Comment: Before creating a job, you have to start a deamon. How did you start this deamon? https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/pgagent_install.html#daemon-installation-on-unix

Comment: After installation, I have created extensions for pgagent and postgis using  CREATE EXTENSION postgis;  CREATE EXTENSION pgagent; . Restarted the pgagent,  systemctl restart pgagent_14.  Also checked the status systemctl status pgagent_14 , it is showing fine. I am using centos7 server . Thanks for help.